# How to get Backbone.Collection.remove to remove instance from server?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Backbone.Collection.remove removes a model from a collection in the front end. Is there a way to make the changes persist to the backend? ie. I want to do a DELETE request on the collection's URL and pass in the model. How would I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`model.destroy();` will remove the model from the collection and make a `DELETE` request to the server.

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy